# Carregar DLL SSL - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Estou tendo problemas para fazer download de arquivos com protocolo https://. Buscando informações, me informaram que devo carregar as DLL. Encontrei pessoas mostrando "como carrega", mas como nunca realizei este procedimento, estou tendo muita dificuldade.

Antes eu havia tentado adicionar o componente da indy, mas obtive erros, por isso que esta é minha "última solução":

```
uses: IdHTTP, IdSSLOpenSSL;

IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.create(nil);
 try
            IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);  
            IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
            IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
            IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
            IdHTTP1.get(FNomeArq,MS);
            Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
            header := IdHTTP1.Response.ContentType;
 except on E : EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
             showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
            on E: EIdSocketError do begin
                showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
            on E: Exception do begin
              showmessage(intToStr(IdHTTP1.ResponseCode));
            end;
 end;
```

> Eu fiz um aplicativo que usa as DLLs openssl ( libeay32.dll e
>   ssleay32.dll ). É indy usá-los, eu não chamar as DLLs diretamente.
>
> A solução mais simples que eu encontrei para evitar um instalador (i
>   apenas delpoy um exe e eu estou ok com esta abordagem) é:
>
> colocar as DLLs como recursos do exe no início do programa que eu
>   extraí-los na pasta exe o exe usa-los

Baixei as DLL aqui:

http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Peguei alguns exemplos na internet, mas não obtive nenhum sucesso:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

type

  // vamos declarar um tipo function
  TSomarFuncao = function(a, b: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  Somar: TSomarFuncao; // uma variável que representará a função
  DLLHandle: THandle; // este é o handle para a DLL
begin
  // vamos carregar a DLL
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('\dll\libeay32.dll');
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('\dll\ssleay32.dll');
  try
    // vamos obter o endereço da função na DLL
    Somar := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'Somar');

    // vamos chamar a função agora
    if Assigned(Somar) then
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(Somar(4, 3)))
    else
      ShowMessage('Não foi possível chamar a rotina desejada');
  finally
    FreeLibrary(DLLHandle); // vamos liberar a DLL
  end;

end;
```

Como faço para carregar essas DLL em minha aplicação?

Comment: Considere utilizar Indy ao invés de tentar fazer isso manualmente.

Comment: O meu problema é que não está funcionando com a Indy...

Comment: Será muito mais fácil tentar fazer funcionar com a Indy do que tentar fazer manualmente. De qualquer forma você vai ter que utilizar a Indy para enviar as requests não vai? Qual outro componente você iria utilizar?

Comment: O Componente em questão é o TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL

Comment: Até onde você foi para fazer funcionar com a Indy? Poste seu progresso para tentarmos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Eu adicionei o código que continha a parte do `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` , mas como eu disse, não funcionou gerou erro... daí em um tópico me indicaram adicionar as DLL. No meu caso uso o delphi XE5, e não formato o PC a mais ou menos 3 anos... ATT

Comment: Como estão as propriedades do IOHandler? Você poderia fazer um código para mínima reprodução do problema criando os componentes em runtime ao invés de design time? Poderia ser uma aplicação console... Dessa forma poderemos analisar se falta alguma configuração.

Comment: Além disso, descreva os erros que estão acontecendo. Isso facilita na resolução do problema. Uma outra informação importante é onde está ocorrendo o problema, em outras palavras, qual linha gera exceção?

Comment: Boa tarde @EProgrammerNotFound, o erro que estava aparecendo era este: `eidosslcouldnotloadssllibrary could not load ssl library`. ATT

Comment: Chame a função `WhichFailedToLoad` e poste o resultado das funções que estão faltando

Comment: Já Tentou colocar as .Dll na pasta da aplicação?
Nunca use para o que você está fazendo mais comigo fazer funcionar para envio de E-mail pelo Indy.